# Import file into nested selector

Tags: css, postcss

Is there a postcss solution for importing a file into / nesting inside a selector? I can't get `postcss-import` or `postcss-nested` to do what I'm after.

```
.some-selector {
    @import 'some.css';
}
```

Given a file e.g. `import-me.css` containing

```
div {
    color: red;
}
```

I'd like to process `entry.css`

```
.some-class {
  @import 'import-me.css';
}
```

And see the output

```
.some-class div {
   color: red;
}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: for the trivial example, you can bodge it by using `postcss-nested-import` AND `postcss-nested` but this has a couple of drawbacks because (a) `postcss-nested-import` paths are relative to the script running it, whereas css convention is that imports should be relative to the calling file (b) the maintainer has abandoned it https://github.com/eriklharper/postcss-nested-import/issues/2 <--- this issue in turn references https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/issues/214 which is a dead thread :-(

Comment: [postcss-nested-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-nested-import)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postcss-partial-import` seems to do the trick.

https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-partial-import